# How can I check if a argument has certain propery values?

Tags: c#, restsharp, nsubstitute

I am trying to stub a RestClient to return a specific response for a specific request, which is recognized by checking the end of the URL that is used. This is the code I have come up with:

```cs
_clientStub = Substitute.For<IRestClient>();
_responseStub = Substitute.For<IRestResponse>();
_clientStub
    .Get(
        Arg.Is<IRestRequest>(
            request => request.Resource.EndsWith("config.json")
        )
    )
    .Returns(_responseStub);
```

I receive a `NullReferenceException` for the `Arg.Is<IRestRequest>` part and if I try to save it in a variable for reuse like this the variable evaluates to `null`:

```cs
protected static readonly IRestRequest CONFIG_QUERY =
    Arg.Is<IRestRequest>(
        request => request.Resource.EndsWith("config.json")
    );
```

I was following the second example in the [documentation](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-for-args/) so I am not exactly sure what is going wrong. Any help?

---

## Clarification

For reproducability I created a minimal example:

```cs
[Fact]
public void StackOverflowTest()
{
    RestSharp.IRestClient clientStub = Substitute.For<RestSharp.IRestClient>();
    RestSharp.IRestResponse responseStub = Substitute.For<RestSharp.IRestResponse>();
    clientStub
        .Get(
            Arg.Any<RestSharp.IRestRequest>()
        )
        .Returns(responseStub);
}
```

Yes, there are no assertions in this test. I don't even get to them anyways since the last command already throws and `NullReferenceException`. The interfaces are from [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp), but that should not really matter.

---

## Update

To narrow the problem down I created an even simpler example and now it works:

```cs
public interface IStackOverflowResponse { };
public interface IStackOverflowRequest { };
public interface IStackOverflowClient
{
    IStackOverflowResponse Get(IStackOverflowRequest request);
}

[Fact]
public void StackOverflowTest()
{
    IStackOverflowClient clientStub = Substitute.For<IStackOverflowClient>();
    IStackOverflowResponse responseStub = Substitute.For<IStackOverflowResponse>();
    clientStub
        .Get(
            Arg.Any<IStackOverflowRequest>()
        )
        .Returns(responseStub);
}
```

So now I guess that there is a specific problem with mocking `RestSharp.RestClient`. I guess the problem lies with mocking/stubbing extension methods as the IRestClient does not have a `Get` method by itself, but instead there is an extension method for it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the `Get` function of `IRestClient`... as it has none. This is just an extension method in `RestClientExtensions`. As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/ac875b1b7d8359922c7ce9b5b134fd0a881ea15f/src/RestSharp/RestClientExtensions.cs#L226) it simply calls `Execute` with `Method.GET` as parameter. So the correct way to stub

```cs
clientStub
    .Get(
        Arg.Any<RestSharp.IRestRequest>()
    )
    .Returns(responseStub);
```

is to do this:

```cs
clientStub
    .Execute(
        Arg.Any<RestSharp.IRestRequest>(),
        Method.GET
    )
    .Returns(responseStub);
```

Comment: Thanks for a good answer! I think it could be improved slightly by explaining that NSubstitute [can not mock extension methods](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/how-nsub-works/). Also if [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) is installed it will pick up this issue at compile-time.